# How does GroovyClassLoader/ClassLoader work?

Tags: java, groovy

I'm seeing code like

```
GroovyClassLoader cLoader = new GroovyClassLoader(this.class.getClassLoader())
```

Followed by something like:

```
cLoader.loadClass([class name])
```

I'm interested in what I should know about the `GroovyClassLoader` class and what the purpose of `this.class.getClassLoader()` is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Class loaders work in a vertical hierarchy manner, in fact in java there are three built in class loaders in this hierarchy:

[image: class loader hierarchy]

So when you pass  `this.class.getClassLoader(`) to the constructor you are creating a classloader whose parent is the classloader which loaded the current class, which will give you this kind classloader hierarchy.

[image]

Why creating a classloader this way?, why not get the built-in ones? that is upto you.

But one fact to remind here is *classloaders load classes in a top down fashion*. A classloader asks its parent to load a class, if the parent cant find the class it loads the class by itself ( notice the call is recuring) and another fact is *classloaders have a cache*, loaded classes are cached for sometime.

So I usually use `Thread.currentThread.getClassLoader()` ( which I believe is similar to urs)  because this gives me the loader which loaded the current running thread  and I believe it is near to my other classes and the hope is it might have cached the class I am requesting.

Comment: Thanks! So `GroovyClassLoader cLoader = new GroovyClassLoader(this.class.getClassLoader())` is the same as `GroovyClassLoader cLoader = this.class.getClassLoader()`?

Comment: No!, just refering to the pic, `this.class.getClassLoader` will give you the 4th class loader where as `new GroovyClassLoader(this.class.getClassLoader())` will give you a new class loader which child of the 4th class loader( ie the 5th class loader)

Comment: Aha, but I can still use `this.class.getClassLoader()` with the same effect, right? And can you give me the link in which you found the sketches?

Comment: Yeah sure you can unless you want to craft custom class loader. The images are mine, I just put what understood abt classloaders into a picture.

Comment: Grt glad to know it was helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Groovy is a scripting language and as such, you'll find yourself in a lot of places where you're loading a Groovy script from a file and want to execute it. There are two problems here:

- Groovy code needs a suitable environment
- You eventually want to get rid of the script (and all its classes)

The `GroovyClassLoader` will make sure that scripts (which are loaded while it's active) will work. And when it is garbage collected, it will make sure that all resources can be GC'd as well (otherwise, you would eventually run into problems if the script on disk changed and you wanted to reload it or you would run out memory, etc.)

Groovy code needs access to normal Java classes, that's why you have to give it a parent classloader. The Groovy classloader will ask the parent for anything that it doesn't know itself.

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation, `this.class.ClassLoader()` parameter passed to the constructor is then taken as the created `GroovyClassLoader`'s parent (instead of using the current Thread's context Class loader as parent - the default behavior).

I'm no expert in class loading, but AFAIK the classloader's parent is first called in search for a given class.

As for what should be known about it, I can't tell you any more than is available in the documentation.

Comment: What does a *parent* of a class loader exactly mean?

Comment: In short, ClassLoaders are arranged in a tree structure. http://www2.sys-con.com/ITSG/virtualcd/java/archives/0808/chaudhri/index.html should explain this way better than I can - from a technical side, I only unterstand the general contept of class loading.